# Code which is converted but behaving not properly

Tags: php, coldfusion

i have the following which i successfully converted to coldfusion, as far as i know i am correct in its conversation but the behavoir is annoying, not sure

here is the php variant

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['box_status'])) {
    print '<script type="text/javascript">';
    print '$(function() {';
    foreach ($_SESSION['box_status'] as $openedbox) {
        print 'Popup('.$openedbox['partner_id'].',"'.$openedbox['partner_username'].'",'.$openedbox['box_status'].');';
    }
    print "});";
    print '</script>';
    }
?>
```

cfm variant

```
<cfif isDefined('session.box_status')>
    <cfsavecontent variable="a">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
             for (<cfoutput>#session.box_status#</cfoutput> in openedbox) {
                Popup(#openedbox['partner_id']#,"#openedbox['partner_username']#",#openedbox['box_status']#);
            }
        });
        </script>
    </cfsavecontent>    
    <cfoutput>#a#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Code works fine in php, but i never keeps the session alive in coldfusion if i refresh a page, which php is doing that ''

that is the generated PHP Code with dump

DUMP

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["partner_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["partner_username"]=>
    string(9) "Elizabeth"
    ["box_status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["partner_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["partner_username"]=>
    string(6) "Joseph"
    ["box_status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Code generated by the php code

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function() {Popup(2,"Elizabeth",1);Popup(3,"Joseph",1);});</script>
```

Comment: Have you turn on the session management and checked the timeout. One more thing i can't see javascripts for loop in php cod  but its there in CF.

Comment: Yes, Session Management is enabled and have a good timeout of say 40 minutes

Comment: so if there is no javascript for loop in php, it is actually using a foreach loop, in cfscript we have for loop right

Comment: but your code is not wrapped in <Cfscript></cfscript> if you want to loop on structure then user collection loop

Comment: Curious, you say `it never keeps the session alive`. So the page works the first time and doesn't work upon refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check out your generated html code and you will get idea why it is behaving odd. 
'foreach' in PHP version uses php code but in CFML version it will be print in JavaScript so obviously it will not able to get openedbox variable and you may get error.

Also put  whole text of cfsavecontent tag to avoid multiple cfoutput.

EDIT:

```
<cfif isDefined('session.box_status')>
    <cfsavecontent variable="a"><cfoutput>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            <cfloop array="#session.box_status#" index="openedbox">
                Popup(#openedbox['partner_id']#,"#openedbox['partner_username']#",#openedbox['box_status']#);
            </cfloop>
        });
        </script></cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>    
    <cfoutput>#a#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Comment: what could be the potential way of rewriting it then, i m mixing jquery and coldfusion code, the same as it is happening in php code

Comment: I have added code. The way you were doing for inside cfsavecontent will consider for printing in html and will render on HTML page. You may need use CFLOOP to tell its CFML loop.

Answer (score 0):

If session.box_status in an array, then you can do this just to keep everything as a tag. You are indeed mixing CF and javascript and you would see your for loop output in the javascript were you to view the html.

```
<cfif isDefined('session.box_status')>
<cfsavecontent variable="a">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
<cfoutput>             
    <cfloop  array="#session.box_status# index=openedbox>
            Popup(#openedbox['partner_id']#,"#openedbox['partner_username']#",#openedbox['box_status']#);
        </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
    });
    </script>
</cfsavecontent>    
<cfoutput>#a#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: it is not an array, just simple plain strings as we use in coldfusion

Comment: When you have a for loop, you are looping over a collection, list, or array. What is session.box_status?

Answer (score 0):

This won't be perfect but it's closer to what you are looking for:

```
<cfif isDefined('session.box_status')>
    <cfsavecontent variable="a">

             <cfloop collection="#session.box_status#" item="x">
             <cfoutput>
             Popup(#x['partner_id']#,"#x['partner_username']#",#x['box_status']#);
             </cfoutput>
             </cfloop>
    </cfsavecontent>  

      <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function() {

         <Cfoutput>#a#</CFOUTPUT>

           };

       </script>
</cfif>
```

Note this code assumes that session.box_status is a structure with three members, partner_id, partner_username and box_status. if that's not the case then your first order of business is to figure out exactly what session.box_status *is* since that's the thing you are looping through. Do a dump of that item to give yourself some clues.

The idea here is that you save into your variable "a" just the separate "popup()" calls, then isert them into your JS down the line. There are other ways to do this, but this sort of code is hard to make pretty. good luck :)

EDIT:
Note - you say that it's "simple strings" you want to loop over, yet the PHP code seems to indicate an object of some sort. That's where we ae confused. If it is strings you might need to alter my code to loop over a LIST and extract items at specific positions. But you really need to dump out #session.box_status# to know what you are up against here.

EDIT 2:
ok in that case you need to loop through an array. But it will not be "session" - because session is a structure not an array. So I'm not sure what object name is your starting poing. Dumping out session might give you a clue. In the example below I'm just calling it "thisArray" - you will have to figure that part out. Other than that this is very close to what you are looking for.

```
     <cfloop array="#thisArray#" index="x">
     <cfoutput>
     Popup(#thisArray[x].['partner_id']#,"#thisArray[x].['partner_username']#",#thisArray[x]['box_status']#);
     </cfoutput>
     </cfloop>
```

NOTE: this snippet would replace the cfsavecontent snippet above.

Comment: ok i dumped the php code and here is what i am getting; array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["partner_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["partner_username"]=> string(9) "Elizabeth" ["box_status"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: that did not seems to doing the task, i had figured that php stores sessions as associative arrays, so in coldfusion, we can use the structures, but that is also not helping the code

Comment: @ACF_JJJQ not sure I can help here. you are passing something, but don't seem to know what it is or where it's coming from. Is it a form field? part of the actual session? If it's part of the session then you have rewritten the PHP session handling to be CF session handling right? You don't seem to know _exactly_ what this is.

Comment: @ Hi Mark: Here is the Pastebin what actually is happening on the php code:, The same kinda code i am trying with coldfusion: Here is the Pastebin for PHP Code: http://pastebin.com/JHJKsQKr

Comment: and here is the pastebin for coldfusion specific code: http://pastebin.com/5FYXPucn